# C++ Overload Resolution, userdefined conversion and function template

Tags: c++, function, templates, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

With g++ 3.4 and 4.7 I observed the following strange behavior:

A function template does not match if a user defined conversion is necessary, where a plain function will.
I could not find the corresponding rule in the C++98 Standard. Is g++ correct, (as I assume)? Or is it a bug?

```
template <class T>
int x(auto_ptr_ref<T> p)
{
  return 1;
}
// this would match
/*
int x(auto_ptr_ref<int> p)
{
   return 2;
}
*/
void dummy()
{
  cout << x(auto_ptr<int>()) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC is correct, [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) doesn't consider implicit conversions.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

For your code, `auto_ptr_ref` doesn't match against `auto_ptr`, the deduction of template parameter `T` fails, so the function template `x()` won't be considered for overload resolution at all.